# how can i solve this problem in my dependences of flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

event sent after app closed:
`{id: 0, progressId: null, message: Running "flutter pub get" in theapp...}`
Because masterstudy_app depends on `flutter_html ^1.0.2` which depends on `video_player ^0.10.11+2`, `video_player ^0.10.11+2` is required.
So, because masterstudy_app depends on `video_player 0.10.9`, version solving failed.
event sent after app closed: `{id: 0, progressId: null, finished: true}`
pub get failed (1; So, because masterstudy_app depends on `video_player 0.10.9`, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

Change dependencies video_player 0.10.9 to ^0.10.11+2 in pubcpeck.yaml and click pub get.